# Are changes made to variables in function calls in if conditions permanent?

Tags: java, if-statement, conditional-statements

I want to call a function, but only if it returns a value of true. The function itself modifies global variables when called normally; I would like to know if an `if` statement stores these changes permanently, or whether it just tests the outcome of the function and resets variables to previous values after testing?

In other words, could I use this code:

```
if(function() == true)
   function();
```

and the `function` will only be called once, or will it have been called twice?

Comment: how could that if statement be evaluated if the function was never run?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`function()` is a.. method. Consider this:

```
private boolean function() {
   /* block of code */
   return true;
}
```

When you reach the `if` statement, `function()` is called. Meaning that the *block of code* was executed. Then, `function()` returns *true*.

Now, you entered the `if` block, there.. you execute `function()` again.. Meaning that *block of code* will be executed again.

Usually, when you have a method that returns a `boolean` and do something, you assign the result to a variable:

```
boolean result = function();
```

And then you can ask whatever you want on `result` to see the output of the method (Usually `true` indicates successful run, `false` indicates that something went wrong).

Answer (score 4):

The answer is it will be called once in the conditional, and if it returns true then it will be executed a second time.

Answer (score 1):

The `method` is called twice (provided it returns true on the first run), and whatever changes that `method` makes are permanent unless you explicitly reverse them somehow.

Answer (score 0):

`function()` will be called twice if it returns `true` in, at least, the first instance.

But why would you need to use the return value of a function to decide whether or not to call that function? It's seems that you could incorporate this logic into `function()` itself. You could adjust the return value appropriately if the caller needed to know what `function()` did.

One more remark: If you function is modifying global variables then you ought to consider concurrency issues. You may need to mark `function()` as `synchronized`.

Answer (score 0):

if your function returns `TRUE` in the `IF` condition then your function will be called **twice**.
If it returns `FALSE` the function will be called  **once** inside your `IF` condition

Comment: Small point but the java community doesn't like block capital TRUE and FALSE. This ain't old C here.

Comment: Your right, I typed in capital to make it more `visible` to the reader :)